# Modifying a (PHP Extension creating) Makefile to include C++ classes and code

Tags: php, c++, linux, makefile

This question would best suit someone who is an expert at Linux C++(and C) MAKE FILES, but would also need to have an understanding of PHP Extensions and how to we create them on Linux.

### Context

I am writing a multi-threaded low-level TCP socket related PHP Extension in C++ - targetting Linux(CentOS 6.5 64-bit). As you are probably aware, PHP extensions essentially "extend the functionality " of user-space PHP code.

I chose to write the core functionality and logic in  standard C++ , using a standard C++ makefile(generated by Eclipse CDT), and it creates an standard Linux executable binary called DC.a

Now, I need to be able to call some of the classes(and functions) from a a PHP Extension(and it's exported functions) that I'm creating.

### Other details

PHP Extension writing can be a little bit tricky, as you have to build PHP from source, then use "phpize" , "./configure" and so on, along with a config.m4  file.
This call to phpize AUTO GENERATES a MAKEFILE with a whole host of make-file settings, which is overwhelming me.

### Problem that needs your help

The need I now have, is to "transfer" my standard C++ classes(code) in to the PHP Extension project directory, and get them to compile , build and LINK with the PHP Extension- which as you will know, **is created as a Shared Object(.SO) (on Linux)** - and a .DLL(on Windows).

This issue I have is, essentially, all about **modifying the primary MAKEFILE auto-generated by a call to "phpize", in order to be able to compile and link additional C++ code **(NOT C code).
Basically, I need to add the meat(held in my C++ project), to the bare-bones skeleton PHP extension that I already have developed and have working.

Anyone with knowledge in this area - please feel free to help me, and thank you from my Heart.., in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we do it:

We compile our C++ code in libraries (as you already mentioned) and then link it. Furthermore we tell phpize to activate the C++ compiler.

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(myextension, whether to enable myextension support,
[ --enable-myextension   Enable myextension support])
if test "$PHP_MYEXTENSION" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MYEXTENSION, 1, [Whether you have myExtension])
  PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
  PHP_SUBST(MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_ADD_INCLUDE(../../../include)
  PHP_ADD_INCLUDE(/usr/include)
  PHP_ADD_INCLUDE(/opt/local/include)
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(boost_thread-mt, /opt/local/lib, MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(boost_system-mt, /opt/local/lib, MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(customlib, /path/to/custom/lib, MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
  AC_DEFINE(_ADDITIONAL_DEFINES_,1,[_ADDITIONAL_DEFINES_])
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(MYEXTENSION, src/php.cpp, $ext_shared)
fi
```

In the php.cpp we have to make sure that somethings are in C:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "../config.h"
#endif
#ifdef WIN32
/* PHP Extension headers */    
/* include zend win32 config first */    
#include "zend_config.w32.h"
#endif

extern "C" {
#include "php.h"
#include "php_ini.h"

#ifdef ZTS
#include "TSRM.h"
#endif

#include "zend_exceptions.h"

}
```

and we also have to wrap our C++ Class:

```
zend_object_handlers myExtension_object_handlers;

struct myextension_object {
    zend_object std;
    YourNS::Extension::myExtension *extension;
};
void myExtension_free_storage(void *object TSRMLS_DC)
{
    myextension_object *obj = (myextension_object *)object;
    delete obj->myExtension; 

    zend_hash_destroy(obj->std.properties);
    FREE_HASHTABLE(obj->std.properties);

    efree(obj);
}

zend_object_value myExtension_create_handler(zend_class_entry *type TSRMLS_DC)
{
    zval *tmp;
    zend_object_value retval;

    myextension_object *obj = (myextension_object *)emalloc(sizeof(myextension_object ));
    memset(obj, 0, sizeof(myextension_object ));
    obj->std.ce = type;

    ALLOC_HASHTABLE(obj->std.properties);
    zend_hash_init(obj->std.properties, 0, NULL, ZVAL_PTR_DTOR, 0);
    #if PHP_VERSION_ID < 50399 
    zend_hash_copy(obj->std.properties, &type->default_properties,
                   (copy_ctor_func_t)zval_add_ref, (void *)&tmp, sizeof(zval *));
    #else
    object_properties_init(&obj->std, type);
    #endif

    retval.handle = zend_objects_store_put(obj, NULL,
                                           myExtension_free_storage, NULL TSRMLS_CC);
    retval.handlers = &myExtension_object_handlers;

    return retval;
}
```

Later you can use it all quite convenient:

```
PHP_METHOD(myExtension, __construct)
{
    YourNS::Extension::myExtension *myExt = NULL;
    zval *object = getThis();

    //if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &maxGear) == FAILURE) {
    //    RETURN_NULL();
    //}

    myExt = new YourNS::Extension::myExtension();
    myextension_object *obj = (myextension_object *)zend_object_store_get_object(object TSRMLS_CC);
    obj->extension = myExt;
}

PHP_METHOD(myExtension, connect)
{
    char* host, *user, *secret, *db, *dbtype, *baseschema;
    int host_len, user_len, secret_len, db_len, dbtype_len, baseschema_len;
    long port;

    YourNS::Extension::myExtension *ext;
    myextension_object *obj = (myextension_object *)zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC);
    ext= obj->extension;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "slsssss", &host, &host_len, &port, &user, &user_len, &secret, &secret_len, &db, &db_len, &dbtype, &dbtype_len, &baseschema, &baseschema_len) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }
    if ( ext != NULL) {
        try {
            ext->connect(host, port, user, secret, db, dbtype, baseschema);
        }
        catch (const YourNS::Extension::RuntimeException& e) {
            char* msg;
            msg = estrdup(e.getMessage().c_str());
            zend_throw_exception(zend_exception_get_default(TSRMLS_C), msg, 0 TSRMLS_CC);
            efree(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the detail in your reply. :-) Let me try and get my head around some of the PHP extension related functions you have mentioned and get back to you soon.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've got it all going now. Learning a lot about how to specify source files to the build system using autoconfig and all that.  Also, for any one else who might be developing PHp extensions, **Sara Goleman's articles** on this matter are very very useful.   http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/